# Binding to Dictionary/Array of objects

Tags: wpf, arrays, binding, dictionary, indexer

I have large collection of statuses(bool) that are reached by key (address)

the visual should display each status as different control (for example checkboxes, buttons, radios , etc) - each control is provided with the address of the status it will display

for example 
button1 <- status[55]
checkbox1 <- status[81]
..
etc

my question is if i put INotifyPropertyChanged on whole indexer(if i do it with indexer) - if one value changes does it update all the controls or only the changed one..

I want only one status change to update only one control - not all of them. Is there a way doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It will update all, in Silverlight you could construct a notification that only updates one index. I cannot think of any solution which would let you keep that structure, if you map everything to objects with key and value you could internally notify of value changes...